# OpenSSL BIGNUM issue, when migrating from 1.0.2 to 1.1.1

Tags: c++, c, openssl, openssl-engine

I am facing OpenSSL BIGNUM issue when migrating from 1.0.2 to 1.1.1 version.

I included `openssl/bn.h`, but the compiler says :

> "incomplete type is not allowed   static const  BIGNUM pubmod"

Here is the code:

```
static const BN_ULONG pubkey[] = { 0x64F5FBD3, 0xA308B0FE};

static const BIGNUM pubmod = { (BN_ULONG *) pubkey,
    sizeof(pubkey)/sizeof(BN_ULONG),
    sizeof(pubkey)/sizeof(BN_ULONG),
    0,
    BN_FLG_STATIC_DATA
};
```

I also tried:

```
 BIGNUM *pubmod = BN_new();
```

How can I do it in 1.1.1? Do I need to go with functions with `BN_hex2bn`?

How should I add the pubkey to BIGNUM variable?

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: It's an opaque data structure that should only be manipulated with the appropriate functions. I'm surprised that code ever worked. It's like trying to make a `FILE` without using `fopen()` to do it.

Comment: Under OpenSSL 1.1, you must avoid directly using the members of the `BIGNUM` struct directly. `BIGNUM` is now a `void*` for applications. In reality, a private header has the real definition. It is called `bignum_st` and defined in `types.h`. Also look into `bn_set_static_words`, which should handle your `BN_ULONG pubkey`. (You can find the struct with `grep -IR BIGNUM ./* | grep _st`).

Comment: Thanks for the response, when I trying the function bn_set_static_words(pubmod,pubkey,SIZE(pubkey));  I get the following error.   "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" ,  
 I added #include <internal/bn_int.h>

"declaration is incompatible with"
"void bn_set_static_words(BIGNUM *, const unsigned int *, int)"
          (declared at line 50 of openssl/include/internal/bn_int.h)
Am I missing any header file or somthing